# How to keep Dropdownlist value same after refresh the page

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I have a Dropdownlist

```
<select name="cate">
  <option value="h">India</option>
  <option value="m">USA</option>
  <option value="c">England</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="show">
```

While clicking on show button,in the below table it will show the selected country details.
Details are coming from database,and each click the page will refresh.

My problem is that, if a user selects England on Dropdown list and clicks on show button, it will show the details, but the dropdown list will show the first name only.
I want to show the selected value name.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post code of your jsp and Servlet?

Comment: Your option values are static or dynamic?

Comment: can you please post also the code that generates the dropdown?

Comment: Dropdown values are static .Every thing working properly except dropdown .After the submission Dropdown value is default .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedValue" value="0"/>
```

put the above one in just below of your select tag

and do this in your servlet

```
String selectedValue = `request.getParameter("selectedValue")`
```

now set the selectedValue into the servlet request

create a JS function in your final jsp

```
function selectedValue(){  

    var value =<%=request.getParameter("selectedValue")%>;  
    if(value !=null)  
        {

        document.f1.slvalue.selectedIndex=value ;          

        }    

}
```

call the selectedValue() function on bodyload of your final jsp page. 
**"slvalue"** is a name of your select tag

Answer (score 3):

HTML CODE

```
<input type=hidden id ="selection" name="selection" value="">
<select name="cate">
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('selection').value='h';" value="h">India</option>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('selection').value='m';" value="m">USA</option>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('selection').value='c';" value="c">England</option>
</select>
```

JSP CODE

```
<%
  String selected = request.getParameter("selection");
%>
```

Now when you are on the JSP page you have an indication of what the user selected.
When you render the  element append the **select** attribute to the selected option

eg:
   < option value="h" selected > India < / option >

**UPDATE**
In the place where you display the dropdown you have to do some kind of validation where you need to check the **selection** value and what you are actually printing.

```
if(selected ==null || selected.equals('')){
    //do regular printing of the dropdown as you do now
}else{
  out.print("<select>");
  while(rs.next()){
    if(rs.getString("VALUE").equals(selected )){
        out.print("<option value=\""+rs.getString("VALUE")+"\" SELECTED >"+rs.getString("COUNTRY")+"</option>");
    }else{
        out.print("<option value=\""+rs.getString("VALUE")+"\" >"+rs.getString("COUNTRY")+"</option>");
    }
  }
  out.print("</select>");
}
```

PS: The code is written on the fly and could need some exception handling or some typos may exist

Comment: thank u,bt it is not working.Clicking on my show button,it will go to servlet,In servlet i written select query,After submission the page will refresh ,then option value will be default one.

Comment: The value for the `<select>` (which is the value of the selected option) is already posted with the form (unless it's disabled, but that's not the case here) so saving that value into a hidden input is an unnecessary extra step.

Comment: @Anthony Grist This was to indicate an obvious way to get the selected option so that OP could embed it into his code. You are right that it is something unnessesary

Answer (score 0):

You can add `selected` to an `<option>` tag so that it's the initially selected value for the page.

```
<option value="h" selected>India</option>
```

would select the India option when the page loads.

You'll need to add some logic to your JSP to add `selected` to the correct `<option>` tag depending on the value that was selected when the page was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

For a clean method you can set a cookie.

look at this jquery method: [jQuery cookies setting select drop down value after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358689/jquery-cookies-setting-select-drop-down-value-after-page-refresh)