# How do i retain the selected value of a dropdown in a JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

This is my code of JSP :

```
<%if (session.getAttribute("user").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Chhattisgarh")){ %>
    <select name="district" id="district" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
            <option value="${row.UserDispName_Eng}">${row.UserDispName_Eng}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
<%} else{
    out.println(session.getAttribute("user"));
} %>
```

i need to load another dropdown depending upon the selection made in this dropdown.
i saw a post similar to it, but it didn't worked for me.
[How to keep Dropdownlist value same after refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309662/how-to-keep-dropdownlist-value-same-after-refresh-the-page/11309895#11309895)

what should i do to achieve this.

Comment: that code did not work because he uses the html elements and set one of them selected, but you update the html code itself.

Comment: try to set the variables in jsp to handle the same

Comment: ok, could you be more clear how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing. on selection of any option call one java script function created by you.Write a code to create a new drop down html into it and set condition in that which set the right option as per your selection of first option.

```
onchange="callAnotherDropDown();"
```

Javascript

```
function callAnotherDropDown(){
   html code.
   creation of new drop down.
   condition to select the proper value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the option value selected in session and compare after for example:

```
if(session.getAttribute("user_dispname").equals("${row.UserDispName_Eng}")){

 selected = "selected=\"selected\"";

 }else{

 selected = "";
}

<option ${selected} value="${row.UserDispName_Eng}">${row.UserDispName_Eng}</option>
```